# Making floating element "exist"

Tags: html, css

On my site, I have something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/YRBT4/

Now, the `#second` block is a dynamic object - the server either generates it or not. If it is not in there, then `#fourth` block collapses, and everything looks bad.

How do I make `#third` block to behave just like `#second` one does, but keep it on the right side of the containing element (I don't want to specify any fixed values here)?

Comment: Just add clearing for #fourth … a question about very basic css knowledge btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding clear:right to #forth should solve the problem.

```
#fourth{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    clear:right;
}
```

Comment: That's what I've been looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a `clearfix`:

```
<div id="first"></div>
<div class="clearfix">
    <div id="second"></div>
    <div id="third"></div>
</div>
<div id="fourth"></div>
```

With:

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
    line-height: 0;
    height: 0;
}
```

*note that `.clearfix` is reusable and is the common practice for clearing floating elements*

Comment: _“and is the common practice for clearing floating elements”_ – yes, common id*ot practice I might say … just putting clear on #fourth works equally well here, and does not require any additional markup. (Seriously, I _hate_ it when all those “frameworks” and CMS default templates add these dumb classes to almost everything, instead of using clearing in the appropriate places only. To me that is clearly a sign of people not knowing what they are doing, or going totally over the top in trying to build a “one size fits all” solution … just plain stupid IMHO.)

Comment: @CBroe is right on that, a lot of unnecessary code only to take the easy way out of the trouble.